# flutter : Gradle threw an error while trying to update itself. Retrying the update... Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Tags: java, android, flutter, gradle

[[!] Gradle threw an error while trying to update itself. Retrying the update...
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HI0LR.png)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are not on the stable channel.

Try to switch to the stable channel, using this Command.

```
flutter channel stable
```